# "regexp" function created for SQLite using direct-sqlite, but the operator REGEXP is not available

Tags: regex, sqlite, haskell

I'm using the `direct-sqlite` package for Haskell to query an SQLite database. I need REGEXP matching, so I've constructed a Haskell function that implements the functionality, and inserted it into the database connection.

```
import Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike
import qualified Text.Regex.PCRE.ByteString as PCRE
import Database.SQLite3

data UmeQuery = UmeQuery Text [SQLData]  deriving Show
data Segment = Segment SegmentLabel SegmentStart SegmentEnd Session LabelType Checksum deriving (Show)

runUmeQuery :: UmeQuery -> FilePath -> IO [Segment] 
runUmeQuery eq  dbFile = do
    conn <- open $ pack dbFile
    res <- runUmeQuery' eq conn
    return res

runUmeQuery' :: UmeQuery -> Database -> IO [Segment] 
runUmeQuery' (UmeQuery q args) conn = do
    statement <- prepare conn q
    createFunction conn "regexp" (Just 2) True sqlRegexp
    bind statement args
    res <- fmap reverse $ getRows statement []
    Database.SQLite3.finalize statement
    close conn
    return res

getRows :: Statement  -> [Segment] -> IO [Segment]
getRows stmt  acc = do
  r <- step stmt
  case r of
    Done -> return acc
    Row -> do
      sess <- columnText stmt 0
      lt <- columnText stmt 1
      start <- columnDouble stmt 3
      end <- columnDouble stmt 4
      label <- columnText stmt 5
      checksum <- columnText stmt 6
      getRows stmt ((Segment label start end sess lt checksum):acc)


sqlRegexp :: FuncContext -> FuncArgs -> IO ()
sqlRegexp ctx args = do
    reg <- fmap encodeUtf8 $ funcArgText args 0
    text <- fmap encodeUtf8 $ funcArgText args 1
    res <- pcreRegex reg text
    funcResultInt64 ctx res
    where
        pcreRegex reg b = do
            reC <- pcreCompile reg
            re <- case reC of
                (Right r) -> return r
                (Left (_,e) ) -> fail e
            reE <- PCRE.execute re b
            case reE of
                (Right (Just _)) -> return (1 :: Int64)
                (Right (Nothing)) -> return (0 :: Int64)
                (Left (_,e)) -> fail e -- Not a good idea maybe, but I have no use for error messages.
            where pcreCompile = PCRE.compile defaultCompOpt defaultExecOpt
```

So, basically, the query functions opens a connection, inserts a "regexp" function and executes a query (in a data type). This is according to the manual:

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user
>   function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use
>   of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an
>   application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time,
>   then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to
>   "regexp(Y,X)".
>   https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like

Now, the problem is that the function is not available in queries:

```
> let b = UmeQuery (pack "select * from segments where label REGEXP '.*';") []
*Phonetic.Database.UmeQuery
> out <- runUmeQuery b "./umecore-hs/testdata/umetest.umedb"
*** Exception: SQLite3 returned ErrorError while attempting to perform prepare "select * from segments where label REGEXP '.*';": no such function: REGEXP
```

How do I make it available??

Comment: I don't know Haskell, but this code looks as if it's preparing the statement before installing the function.

Comment: You're right! Of course! Please forgive my stupidity! That works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know Haskell, but this code looks as if it's preparing the
>   statement before installing the function. – CL. 24 mins ago

Silly me.